# How to add columns subsequently in a dataset using Spark within a for loop ( where for loop contains the column name)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Here trying to add subsequently column to dataset Row, the issue coming up is last column is only visible. The columns added earlier do not persist

```
private static void populate(Dataset<Row> res, String[] args)
    {
        String[] propArr = args[0].split(",");   // Eg: [abc, def, ghi]       
            
        // Dataset<Row> addColToMergedData = null;
        
        /** Here each element is the name of the column to be inserted */
        for(int i = 0; i < propArr.length; i++){

            // addColToMergedData = res.withColumn(propArr[i], lit(null));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logic in the *for loop* is flawed hence the issue.
you can modify the program as follows :

```
private static void populate(Dataset<Row> res, String[] args)
        {
                String[] propArr = args[0].split(",");   // Eg: [abc, def, ghi]       
               
                Dataset<Row> addColToMergedData = null;
        
                /** Here each element is the name of the column to be inserted */
                for(int i = 0; i < propArr.length; i++)
                {
                    res = res.withColumn(propArr[i], lit(null));
                }
                addColToMergedData  = res

        }
```

Comment: Looking for more cleaner and efficient way to resolve this. As I have read that this chaining method using withColumn is not perf efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the clean and conscious way to do this by using Scala:

```
val columnsList = Seq("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")

val res = columnsToBeAdded.foldLeft(baseDataFrame) { case (df, columnName) =>   df.withColumn(columnName, lit(null)) }
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. I suggest improvment readability by: `val res = columnsToBeAdded.foldLeft(baseDataFrame) { case (df, columnName) =>
  df.withColumn(columnName, lit(null))
}`. If your `baseDataFrame` has already some column from `columnList` it will be overridden  by `null`. So suggestion for precise and name it `columnsToBeAdded`

Answer (score 0):

Sol:

// addColToMergedData = res.withColumn(colMap.get(propArr[i]), lit(null));

should be written as :
res = res.withColumn(colMap.get(propArr[i]), lit(null));